# Data transmission through multiple IoT devices

Tags: wifi, data, transmission, device

We are implementing a device which will have multiple sensors inside multiple houses in our local area.

Each house will have 1 device fixed at a place and data will be transmitted to one central location. But the problem is we cannot install WiFi on these devices, it should work with cellular network.i.e. 2G,4G Or NB-IoT.

What is the best approach to implement this? Please suggest some good IOT devices which support cellular network transmission.

Comment: Smarthome stuff with Cellular Network? never heard of this... DECT, Zigbee, Z-Wave,... these are common

Comment: Asking shopping questions (part recommendations) will have your question closed. (See [On-topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).) Please [edit] to remove that part.

Comment: This is an shopping question (so not for this site). Also, you say you can't install WiFi but you don't say you can't used bluetooth or the multitude of other options. You haven't given a reason why you can't use Ethernet or other wired comms (as they're all in fixed locations).

Comment: @schnedan pretty common consideration for larger company campuses: if you have 10000 say light and brightness sensors distributed across that, you can basically either start operating your own IoT cellular network, or you can pay someone that knows how to operate cellular networks. This is literally why NB-IoT was invented!

Comment: @MarcusMüller the OP mentioned some houses in the neighbourhood - guess that does not include a company budget... for running a own cellular network

Comment: @schnedan exactly, that's why you'd just buy subscriptions for the couple of devices you have and get a working network!